# Enlarging/shrinking while maintaining aspect ratio when using Google Earth Pro to Edit Image Overlay?

Tags: georeferencing, google-earth, overlay

In Google Earth Pro "Edit Image Overlay", the only way I have found to enlarge
or shrink the overlay **while maintaining the X:Y aspect ratio** is to
grab one of the four green corners (**not** the four middle of edge
"T"s), and **carefully** pull it in a direction *exactly* toward or away
from the image center "+". Is there any better way?
(Note Properties > Location > Fit to screen wipes out rotation.)

Comment: In Windows OS, I hold [Shift] key while moving corners.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Kazuhito! Indeed one finds that holding SHIFT while moving any of the 4 corners, or four "T" edges, will all do the same job: proportional scaling!
(Also noted in https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148099 .) Works on Linux too.
(Alas, one must zoom out to be able to access these eight items if one is too zoomed in. But then one cannot see what one was trying to look at.)

Comment: Just to clarify, you have to press (and hold) shift before starting to move the corner.  Many other programs allows you to start pressing shift after the mouse press which resets and fixes the aspect ratio, google earth doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the Reset button under the View tab to get the orig. aspect ratio.